# What causes a "The search key was not found in any record" error in Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, corruption

The error message "The search key was not found in any record" was appearing on one record of a table in Access 2010.

I first noticed this when accessing that record via an update query, but later found that I also got the same error when trying to delete the record.

What causes this, and how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was just a database corruption, but I was misled by it only affecting one record. A Compact and Repair sorted it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens because the field name contains a leading space, ensure your field names are trimmed before and after.
Example: It happened to me when I was trying to import an Excel sheet contains the first row as field  names, two of the field names was " Latitude" and " Longitude". From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) I knew the problem's cause, so I changed them to "Latitude" and "Longitude" (*without the leading space*), and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but i just ran into this issue and none of the other answers seemed to solve or address my scenario.

Using a copy of the dbase, i had to continue to delete tables until the error message ceased.

The table at fault was a hidden, system table with the name MSysComplexColumns.  I deleted it, closed the dbase and the table was auto-created upon re-opening the dbase.  That completed solved it with no side effects.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error message was triggered by the size of my Access file. When its size exceeded 2,000,000 KB, the message popped up when I was importing another document. As long as I reduced its size, the message stopped and the import process finished successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Also check the database version.  I was having the problem with VBA CreateDatabase(sTempDBName, dbLangGeneral) in Access 2010 where I was using a 2003 database trying to link a table in a 2010 database.  When I manually tried the link I got a message about no support for linking to a later version.  Creating the temp database I was trying to link to using the option dbVersion40 "CreateDatabase(sTempDBName, dbLangGeneral, dbVersion40)" cured it.